# Ubuntu doesn't recognize extended logical volume, 18.04

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, lvm

I use an lvm, one for /home and another for /root (and another for swap, but that doesn't matter here). This lvm consists of 2 hard drives: one is 1.82 Tb, and the other is 476 Gb. My /home is 2 Tb, my /root is 25Gb, swap is 6 Gb.

Recently my /root lvm partition has been running out of space so I extended it by 25 Gb using the lvextend command. There were no errors and I went about my business. See lvdisplay output below.

```
~$ sudo lvdisplay
(truncated for brevity) 
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/computer/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                computer
  LV Size                2.00 TiB

--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/computer/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                computer
  LV Size                50.00 GiB

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/computer/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                computer
  LV Size                6.00 GiB
```

However, it seems that ubuntu doesn't recognize that the lvm has been extended. I still get the warnings that my disk space will run out in the /root partition. You can see this in the Ubuntu Disk Usage Analyzer, which does not recognize the change.

[image: Ubuntu Disk Usage Analyzer run as root]

I was worried that I extended the lv without having enough free space, but the vgdisplay command tells me that there is 235 GiB of free space in this volume group.

**My question:** What's going on here and what can I do to fix this? Why does Ubuntu not recognize the extended logical volume? Is there something that I missed when extending the logical volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you've resized the volume (the container), but not the *filesystem*, so the OS can only see the filesystem that already exists, and what *it* thinks is the space available.

There are two ways of extending a logical volume that contains a filesystem, essentially:

- Automatically, getting LVM to try to resize the filesystem in the process, i.e. using the `lvresize` command with the `--resizefs` flag. Depending on your filesystem, this may or may not work. In your case the full command would have been `lvresize --resizefs --size +25G /dev/computer/root`. It's too late to do this, so you can use the second method:
- Manually, using separate `lvextend` and `resize2fs` commands. This should work for ext4 and other commonly used filesystems but may not work for some. I leave it up to you to find out whether you filesystem of choice can be extended. In this case, try running **`resize2fs /dev/computer/root`**, in order to grow the filesystem to the available space in its container.

There is a blog post covering how to do this [here](https://www.systutorials.com/extending-a-mounted-ext4-file-system-on-lvm-in-linux/).

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you. I'll do it the first way here on out.

Comment: Whilst it is not directly related to the context, I found this a useful resource for the latter suggested method https://ntalam.com/2020/06/13/virtualbox-no-space-left-on-device/