# LVM partition not seen

Tags: partitioning

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Server
I increased the LVM PV partition with live gparted from 7 to 17 G but the system can't see yet the 17 G. Instead other disk utils (gparted, fdisk, etc) reports 17 G. How can I fix that? Thanks folks!

```
lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 498.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0    17G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0     7G  0 lvm  /

vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <16.94 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              4336
  Alloc PE / Size       1791 / <7.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       2545 / 9.94 GiB
  VG UUID               frHn5C-8jpB-Fq7N-SBiw-Hi60-ndAc-eFJQb0

lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  LV Name                ubuntu-lv
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                pbJ92z-o62R-3iHv-Cj6F-9Z8W-SP9J-5K6QUl
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2020-12-11 22:33:57 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <7.00 GiB
  Current LE             1791
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```

Comment: Did you resize the filesystem, or just the logical volume? See for example [Ubuntu doesn't recognize extended logical volume, 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1227192/178692)

Comment: I think /dev/sd3 is a primary partition and the problem is that I can't  resize the lvm to utilize the whole sda3 (17G).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `parted`, `fdisk`, `gdisk`, etc. you only change the partition table on the disk. Since your old partitions are still in use by your system, it keeps using it with the information (start sector and size) it got at boot.

For your system to take into account your new partition table, you need to call `partprobe`. Then you will need to call `pvresize` and finally `lvresize --resizefs`.

Edit: hmmm, according to your `vgdisplay` output, apparently `gparted` took care of the `partprobe` and `pvresize` parts for you, then you just have to execute `lvresize --resizefs` on `/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               448M     0  448M   0% /dev
tmpfs                               99M  1.1M   98M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   17G  4.6G   12G  29% /
tmpfs                              491M  8.0K  491M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              491M     0  491M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  198M  712M  22% /boot
Documents                          308G   99G  210G  33% /media/sf_Documents
Downloads                          308G   99G  210G  33% /media/sf_Downloads
Linux                              308G   99G  210G  33% /media/sf_Linux
tmpfs                               99M  4.0K   99M   1% /run/user/1000
```