# Showing different storage size in lsblk and df -h after resizing the LVM root partition

Tags: 18.04

I resized the LVM root partition using below command

1. Open Gparted from the GUI, resize it the lvm ubuntu-vg partition
2. `sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`
3. reboot it

Now i checking the size showing different in `df -h` and `lsblk`

`df -h` (showing 1 tb) while `lsblk` showing 2TB
[image: df -h]

[image: sudo lsblk]

Comment: It looks like you didn't tell lvextend to resize the filesystem - see [Ubuntu doesn't recognize extended logical volume, 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227146/ubuntu-doesnt-recognize-extended-logical-volume-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
I follow the below steps, after showing the extract resizing partition in df -h as well lsblk.

```
sudo df -h
sudo lvs
sudo vgs
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
sudo reboot now
```